# How can I filter by calculated field without using groups in tableau?

Tags: tableau-desktop

So I am working on a Tableau Dashboard. On the worksheet I'm working on I had to create 50-75 calculated fields. Now I am running into an issue where I dont know how to group all the calculated fields as that is not an option. I have tried a few things.

1. I tried doing an if then statement but it isn't working because floating values cant use and.
2. Then I tried to do an Case when then statements. That works but im not sure how to get it into a format i can use to filter.
3. I was told a parameter might work but i am running into an issue because i would have to run each calculated field instead of a group of multiple fields.

Does anyone have some suggestions to help with this?

Comment: i'm not very clear on the situation -- do you mean a `case when` is throwing errors due to data type mismatch? then you can cast the column(s) to your desired format inside the cases. -- do you mean you want a single field with all calculations? then parameter would help, just use `case when` with the parameter value(s) (they work same as columns).

Comment: So when i use a case when statement I throw the calculated field into the filter and i get a bunch of options for stuff but i dont know what to choose. Any time i do it gives me 4 options and all four will give me an invalid error where no filter is actually generated

Comment: it'll be helpful if you could elaborate that in your question. what options are you looking for, what do you start with and what do you expect -- these things will help us pinpoint

Comment: I dont know how to get groups inside a filter. Below is an example of what im looking at.

On a basic level I have six cars car 1&2 are on team A. car 3 is on team b. Cars 4-6 are on team c. I have all six cars listed right now. The client would like to be able to filter by team and have the cars show that are on that team. Each of the cars has speed at different points in time. I am using a measured field to be able to display all of them. That's why I have calculated fields for each. I'm not sure how I can group them and then filter.

Comment: isn't this embedded in your backend data fields? if not, this feels like a `case when` job where you create teams based on cars data (or vice versa depending on what you have in your data) like, `case when [car] in (1, 2) then 'A' when [car] in (3) then 'B' when [car] in (4, 5) then 'C' end` will create A, B & C teams for the cars. the resulting calculated field can then be used as a filter.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.